# Juniper bytes-from-server meaning

Tags: networking, firewall, juniper

I'm looking through some Juniper firewall logs that look like [this](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.1/topics/reference/general/session-log-entry-information-for-srx-series.html). There are servers and user machines on the network. Most of the logs refer to source and destination, which makes sense to me, but some values in the log such as "bytes-from-server" refer to a client and a server. How does Juniper designate who is the client and who is the server? Is there any documentation around this?

Answer (score 1):

So after asking around with some co-workers, we've decided that "Client" refers to the computer initiating the connection, and "Server" refers to the computer receiving the connection.